# Error running Gradle?

Tags: flutter

Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\Any\AndroidStudioProjects\vme\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not download kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.0/kotlin-reflect-1.2.0.jar'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.0/kotlin-reflect-1.2.0.jar'.
  >   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Read timed out
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 41s

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
f

Comment: Sounds like a temporary network problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would also say it is either a network problem or intellij not being able to target the endpoints, you can check the cache for intellij and clear the cache maybe.

You should also see wether you can download the dependencies by accessing the url on a browser.